# rosbag how to slow rate

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to slow the rate for rosbag file.
I tried the following but does not seem to work.
Any idea how to do this?

rosbag play --rate .5 rgbd_dataset_freiburg1_xyz.bag

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271393/rosbag-how-to-slow-rate/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just double checked your syntax above and it works fine on my setup. The --rate or -r arguments are exactly what you need. Could you try a more extreme factor, maybe 0.1 to check for sure.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2